# print html entities in link drupal

Tags: theming

```
l('Visit Website &raquo;', 'http://' . $site->purl_prefix . '.' . $base)
```

I have a link I want to print like this the » is not getting parse properly it is still showing up as the character code in the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass `html => TRUE` as an option:

```
$options = array('html' => TRUE);
l('Visit Website &raquo;', 'http://' . $site->purl_prefix . '.' . $base, $options);
```

From [the docs](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/7):

> **'html' (default FALSE):** Whether $text is HTML or just plain-text. For example, to make an image tag into a link, this must be set to TRUE, or you will see the escaped HTML image tag. $text is not sanitized if 'html' is TRUE. The calling function must ensure that $text is already safe.